# Getting nested properties with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json

I am working with `System.Text.Json` in my project as I am processing large files so also decided to use it for processing GraphQL responses.

Due to the nature of GraphQL sometimes I get highly nested responses that are not fixed and don't make sense to map to a class.  I usually need to check a few properties on the response.

My issue is with `JsonElement`. To check nested properties feels very clumsy and I feel like there should be a better way to approach this.

For example take my below code simulating a response I get.  I just want to check if 2 properties exist (id & originalSrc) and if they do get their value but it feels like I have made a meal of the code.  Is there a better/clearer/more succinct way to write this?

```
var raw = @"{
""data"": {
""products"": {
    ""edges"": [
        {
            ""node"": {
                ""id"": ""gid://shopify/Product/4534543543316"",
                ""featuredImage"": {
                    ""originalSrc"": ""https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0286/pic.jpg"",
                    ""id"": ""gid://shopify/ProductImage/146345345339732""
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
}";

var doc = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(raw);

JsonElement node = new JsonElement();

string productIdString = null;

if (doc.TryGetProperty("data", out var data))
    if (data.TryGetProperty("products", out var products))
        if (products.TryGetProperty("edges", out var edges))
            if (edges.EnumerateArray().FirstOrDefault().ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Undefined && edges.EnumerateArray().First().TryGetProperty("node", out node))
                if (node.TryGetProperty("id", out var productId))
                    productIdString = productId.GetString();

string originalSrcString = null;

if(node.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Undefined && node.TryGetProperty("featuredImage", out var featuredImage))
    if (featuredImage.TryGetProperty("originalSrc", out var originalSrc))
        originalSrcString = originalSrc.GetString();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productIdString))
{
    //do stuff
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(originalSrcString))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

It is not a crazy amount of code but checking a handful of properties is so common I would like a cleaner more readble approach.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could add a couple of extension methods that access a child `JsonElement` value by property name or array index, returning a nullable value if not found:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonElement? Get(this JsonElement element, string name) => 
        element.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Null && element.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Undefined && element.TryGetProperty(name, out var value) 
            ? value : (JsonElement?)null;
    
    public static JsonElement? Get(this JsonElement element, int index)
    {
        if (element.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Null || element.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Undefined)
            return null;
        // Throw if index < 0
        return index < element.GetArrayLength() ? element[index] : null;
    }
}
```

Now calls to access nested values can be chained together using the null-conditional operator [`?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-):

```
var doc = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(raw);

var node = doc.Get("data")?.Get("products")?.Get("edges")?.Get(0)?.Get("node");

var productIdString = node?.Get("id")?.GetString();
var originalSrcString = node?.Get("featuredImage")?.Get("originalSrc")?.GetString();
Int64? someIntegerValue = node?.Get("Size")?.GetInt64();  // You could use "var" here also, I used Int64? to make the inferred type explicit.
```

Notes:

- The extension methods above will throw an exception if the incoming element is not of the expected type (object or array or null/missing).  You could loosen the checks on [`ValueKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.valuekind?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonElement_ValueKind) if you never want an exception on an unexpected value type.
- There is an open API enhancement request *[Add JsonPath support to JsonDocument/JsonElement #31068](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31068)*.  Querying via [JSONPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm), if implemented, would make this sort of thing easier.
- If you are porting code from Newtonsoft, be aware that `JObject` returns `null` for a missing property, while `JArray` throws on an index out of bounds.  Thus you might want to use the [`JElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.item?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonElement_Item_System_Int32_) array indexer directly when trying to emulate Newtonsoft's behavior, like so, since it also throws on an index out of bounds:

  ```
  var node = doc.Get("data")?.Get("products")?.Get("edges")?[0].Get("node");
  ```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3QVH6C).

Comment: Thanks!  Been using this today and it has saved me a ton of time.

Comment: this is awesome, saves so much time!

Answer (score 6):

To make my code a little more readable I created a method that uses a dot-separated path with System.Text.Json similar to a path parameter for the `SelectToken()` method in Newtonsoft.Json.

```
JsonElement jsonElement = GetJsonElement(doc, "data.products.edges");
```

I then use `jsonElement.ValueKind` to check the return type.

```
private static JsonElement GetJsonElement(JsonElement jsonElement, string path)
{
    if (jsonElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Null ||
        jsonElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Undefined)
    {
        return default;
    }

    string[] segments =
        path.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (int n = 0; n < segments.Length; n++)
    {
        jsonElement = jsonElement.TryGetProperty(segments[n], out JsonElement value) ? value : default;

        if (jsonElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Null ||
            jsonElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Undefined)
        {
            return default;
        }
    }

    return jsonElement;
}
```

I created another simple method to retrieve the value of the returned `JsonElement` as a string.

```
private static string GetJsonElementValue(JsonElement jsonElement)
{
    return
        jsonElement.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Null &&
        jsonElement.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Undefined ?
        jsonElement.ToString() :
        default;
}
```

Below are two functions applied to the OP's sample:

```
public void Test()
{
    string raw = @"{
        ""data"": {
        ""products"": {
            ""edges"": [
                {
                    ""node"": {
                        ""id"": ""gid://shopify/Product/4534543543316"",
                        ""featuredImage"": {
                            ""originalSrc"": ""https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0286/pic.jpg"",
                            ""id"": ""gid://shopify/ProductImage/146345345339732""
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        }
    }";

    JsonElement doc = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(raw);

    JsonElement jsonElementEdges = GetJsonElement(doc, "data.products.edges");

    string originalSrcString = default;
    string originalIdString = default;

    if (jsonElementEdges.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array)
    {
        int index = 0; // Get the first element in the 'edges' array

        JsonElement edgesFirstElem =
            jsonElementEdges.EnumerateArray().ElementAtOrDefault(index);

        JsonElement jsonElement =
            GetJsonElement(edgesFirstElem, "node.featuredImage.originalSrc");
        originalSrcString = GetJsonElementValue(jsonElement);

        jsonElement =
            GetJsonElement(edgesFirstElem, "node.featuredImage.id");
        originalIdString = GetJsonElementValue(jsonElement);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(originalSrcString))
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(originalIdString))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Thank [Dave B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5535143/dave-b) for a good idea. I have improved it to be more efficient when accessing array elements without having to write too much code.

```
string raw = @"{
        ""data"": {
        ""products"": {
            ""edges"": [
                {
                    ""node"": {
                        ""id"": ""gid://shopify/Product/4534543543316"",
                        ""featuredImage"": {
                            ""originalSrc"": ""https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0286/pic.jpg"",
                            ""id"": ""gid://shopify/ProductImage/146345345339732""
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    ""node"": {
                        ""id"": ""gid://shopify/Product/123456789"",
                        ""featuredImage"": {
                            ""originalSrc"": ""https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0286/pic.jpg"",
                            ""id"": [
                                ""gid://shopify/ProductImage/123456789"",
                                ""gid://shopify/ProductImage/666666666""
                            ]
                        },
                        ""1"": {
                            ""name"": ""Tuanh""
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        }
    }";
```

Usage is also quite simple

```
JsonElement doc = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(raw);
JsonElement jsonElementEdges = doc.GetJsonElement("data.products.edges.1.node.1.name");



public static JsonElement GetJsonElement(this JsonElement jsonElement, string path)
        {
            if (jsonElement.ValueKind is JsonValueKind.Null or JsonValueKind.Undefined)
                return default;

            string[] segments = path.Split(new[] {'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (var segment in segments)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(segment, out var index) && jsonElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array)
                {
                    jsonElement = jsonElement.EnumerateArray().ElementAtOrDefault(index);
                    if (jsonElement.ValueKind is JsonValueKind.Null or JsonValueKind.Undefined)
                        return default;

                    continue;
                }

                jsonElement = jsonElement.TryGetProperty(segment, out var value) ? value : default;

                if (jsonElement.ValueKind is JsonValueKind.Null or JsonValueKind.Undefined)
                    return default;
            }

            return jsonElement;
        }

        public static string? GetJsonElementValue(this JsonElement jsonElement) => jsonElement.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Null &&
                                                                                   jsonElement.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Undefined
            ? jsonElement.ToString()
            : default;
```

Answer (score 4):

I have developed a small library named JsonEasyNavigation, you can get it on [github](https://github.com/sharkadi-a/JsonEasyNavigation) or from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonEasyNavigation/). It allows you to navigate through JSON Domain Object Model using indexer-like syntax:

```
var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
var nav = jsonDocument.ToNavigation();
```

ToNavigation() method converts JsonDocument into readonly struct named JsonNavigationElement. It has property and array item indexers, for example:

```
var item = nav["data"]["product"]["edges"][0];
```

Then you can check for actual items existince like this:

```
if (item.Exist)
{
   var id = item["id"].GetStringOrEmpty();
   // ...
}
```

I hope you will find it useful.

Comment: Does .NET's Json really need an additional library to do something like this, which should be very common? I mean, I have been using Newtonsoft Json, and thought of using .NET's, to reduce the number of external libraries, but if I have to add another library just to do common tasks like this, it defeats the very purpose of transitioning from Newtonsoft's. I may just keep using Newtonsoft Json.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of JsonElement  returned you have to handle it differently.

My case was that the returned element was ValueKind = Array : "[[47.751]]"
So in order to get it I did created this method

```
private object GetValueFromJsonElement(WorkbookRange range)
{
    // The RootElement is the JsonElement
    var element = range.Values.RootElement.EnumerateArray().First()[0];
    switch (element.ValueKind)
    {
        case JsonValueKind.Number:
            return element.GetDouble();

        case JsonValueKind.String:
            return element.GetString();

        case JsonValueKind.True:
        case JsonValueKind.False:
            return element.GetBoolean();
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The Value Type returned is not handled");
    }
}Depending on the type of JsonElement  returned you have to handle it differently.
```