# Indexing JsonElement Array

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

Dear Community Members

Despite online searches, it is wondered how to efficiently `index` and `retrieve` corresponding values of a `JsonElement Array` using `C#`:

```
 string srep2 = " [ " + srep + " ] ";
 using JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(srep2);
 var p = root[0]; // ValueKind = Object
 var a = p.GetProperty("resources"); //ValueKind = Array
```

*Where p =*

```
" [ {\"meta\":{\"collection_type\":\"json\",\"collection_total\":1},\"resources\":[{\"created_by\":\"ccccccc\",\"creation_date\":\"2021-12-10T14:02:53Z\",\"cd\":\"com\",\"description\":\"sample.\",\"uploaded\":true,\"id\":\"I\",\"labels\":[],\"last_update_date\":\"2021-12-10T14:02:53Z\",\"name\":\"TEST\",\"question\":{\"answer\":\"test-answer\",\"pseudo\":\"dv\"},\"key\":\"gk\",\"subject\":\"natural_science\",\"place\":2,\"state\":\"aj\",\"version\":[{\"auto\":false,\"created_by\":\"e2\",\"creation_date\":\"2021-12-10T14:02:53Z\",\"upload\":true,\"id\":\"sdsd\",\"available\":true}],\"total_vegetable\":1}]} ] "
```

*And a =*

```
  [{\"created_by\":\"ccccccc\",\"creation_date\":\"2021-12-10T14:02:53Z\",\"cd\":\"com\",\"description\":\"sample.\",\"uploaded\":true,\"id\":\"I\",\"labels\":[],\"last_update_date\":\"2021-12-10T14:02:53Z\",\"name\":\"TEST\",\"question\":{\"answer\":\"test-answer\",\"pseudo\":\"dv\"},\"key\":\"gk\",\"subject\":\"natural_science\",\"place\":2,\"state\":\"aj\",\"version\":[{\"auto\":false,\"created_by\":\"e2\",\"creation_date\":\"2021-12-10T14:02:53Z\",\"upload\":true,\"id\":\"sdsd\",\"available\":true}],\"total_vegetable\":1}]} ] "
```

*Purposes:*

**(1) Indexing or finding the "name" property in Array [a];
(2) Retrieving its corresponding value: "TEST"**

*N.B:* None of the combination performed independently has succeeded so far... hence this post.

Thanks in advance.
Best

Comment: You are using [tag:system.text.json] not [tag:json.net].  If you want to access items inside a `JsonDocument` or `JsonElement` see [Getting nested properties with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561343/3744182).  Beyond that it's not clear exactly where your problem is, can you [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

you can put everything in one line

```
string name=string.Empty;

using (var doc  = JsonDocument.Parse(srep2) )
 name = doc.RootElement[0][0].GetProperty("resources")[0]
.GetProperty("name").ToString();
```

output

```
TEST
```

Comment: `JsonDocument` must be disposed.