# Converting Newtonsoft code to System.Text.Json which is using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I need help in converting following code which is using newtonsoft to System.Text.Json

```
string myList = null!;
string jSon = /* From some source */;
object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jSon, typeof(object));

// Loop through the keys
foreach (var jsonList in ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)(jsonObject)))
{                   
    if (jsonList.Key == "myKey")
    {                       
        foreach (object o in (jsonList.Value.ToArray()))
        {                           
            myList += o.ToString().ToUpper() + ',';
        }
    }
}
```

json like:

```json
{"myKey":["fir","dsdsd"],"status":"ok"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With System.Text.Json, you can parse arbitrary JSON using either the [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#use-jsondocument) or [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#use-jsonnode) document object models.  The [differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter#json-dom-choices) are:

- [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode?view=net-6.0) is modifiable and is, in my opinion, easier to work with as it most closely resembles Newtonsoft's LINQ to JSON model.  It was added in [.NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-6#writeable-dom).
- [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=net-6.0) is read-only, but may be a little more memory-efficient in parsing huge JSON files.  It was introduced as part of the original System.Text.Json API in [.NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.0).

Thus, using `JsonNode`, your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
static string? QueryJson(string json, string myKey, bool addComma = false)
{
    // Parse to a JsonNode and cast to JsonObject.  An exception is thrown if not an object
    var node = JsonNode.Parse(json)!.AsObject(); 
    
    // Query the array of strings
    var query = (node[myKey] as JsonArray)?.Select(i => i?.ToString().ToUpper());
    if (query == null)
        return null; // Return null if key not found as per original code
    if (addComma)
        query = query.Concat(new [] { "" });

    // Join the string array into a single comma-separated string
    return string.Join(',', query);
}
```

And here is a version of the same logic using `JsonDocument`:

```
static string? QueryJsonWithJsonDocument(string json, string myKey, bool addComma = false)
{
    // Parse to a JsonNode and cast to JsonObject.  An exception is thrown if not an object
    using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);

    // Query the array of strings
    var query = doc.RootElement.Get(myKey)?.EnumerateArray().Select(e => e.GetString()?.ToUpper());
    if (query == null)
        return null; // Return null if key not found as per original code
    if (addComma)
        query = query.Concat(new [] { "" });

    // Join the string array into a single comma-separated string
    return string.Join(',', query);
}
```

This uses the following extension method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561343/3744182) to check for missing or null properties:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonElement? Get(this JsonElement element, string name) => 
        element.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Null && element.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Undefined && element.TryGetProperty(name, out var value) 
            ? value : (JsonElement?)null;
}
```

Notes:

- You tagged your question [.net-core-3.1](/questions/tagged/.net-core-3.1).  This version goes out of support in about a month, on [December 13, 2022](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core).  If you are using this version you will need to use `JsonDocument` since `JsonNode` was introduced in .NET 6.
- `JsonDocument` is disposable, and should be disposed to ensure that pooled memory is returned to the system.  `JsonNode` is not disposable.
- It will be more efficient to use `string.Join()` than manually building a comma-separated string using multiple string additions.
- Your current code adds a trailing comma to the string: `FIR,DSDSD,`.  This looks like a bug, but if you want that you can make `string.Join()` add a trailing comma by adding an extra empty string to the query.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jHECGT).

Comment: thanks @dbc. i know 3.1 is expiring but there are places where even 2.1/2.2 is used in production. luckily my this logic is in .net 6 solution so i will use the JsonNode solution. about the trailing comma i have a legacy code where first they create string like initial solution then removed it via extension method :)